# Python coding question - Slicing and Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, slice

Two dictionaries, `dct5` and `dct6`, are defined in a cell below. Use a for loop to add the items in dct5 to dct6. Note: there is a dictionary method `update()` that can do this, but I want a solution that uses a for loop.
Use a `for loop` to create a dictionary `dct7` whose keys are the integers 1,2,...,10 and whose values are the cubes of the keys.

```
In [47]:

dct5 = {2:4, 3:9, 4:16}
​
dct6 = {5:25, 6:36, 7:49}


dct7 = {}
​
for _ in range(10):
```

How would I continue this code?

Comment: Is this a test you have to solve?

Comment: In your for-loop, you should iterate over `dct5.items()` See https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/items

Comment: No, it was an example problem in my notes that I didn't get solved in class. Thank you for the helpful link though. @jonathan.scholbach

Answer (score 1):

```
dct5 = {2:4, 3:9, 4:16}
​
dct6 = {5:25, 6:36, 7:49}


dct7 = {}
​
# Standard for loop Approach
for i in range(10):
    dct7[i] = i**3

# Dictionary Comprehension Approach
dct7 = {i:i**3 for i in range(10)}
```

Answer (score -1):

First question:

1. In Python 3.5 or greater:

   `dct7 = {**dct5,**dct6}`

Output:

```
{2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49}
```

Cubes by Comprehension

```
{k:k**3 for k in range(1,11)}
```

Output:
{1: 1, 2: 8, 3: 27, 4: 64, 5: 125, 6: 216, 7: 343, 8: 512, 9: 729, 10: 1000}